# Destroy Anchors in Unity ARCore

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I have a project that places a game object on the position a user touches the screen. An anchor is made as such:

```
private Anchor anchor;

anchor = detectedPlane.CreateAnchor (new Pose (anchorPosition, Quaternion.identity));

transform.position = anchorPosition;

transform.SetParent (anchor.transform);
```

Right before creating an anchor when a user touches the screen the second time or any number of times after that, I make sure to destroy the anchor with the following code.

```
if (anchor != null) {
    Destroy(anchor);
}
```

However, when I test my code on Instant Preview, all of the anchors remain after I touch the screen multiple times. Is this the right way of destroying anchors?

Comment: What is anchor declared as? What type is it? You need to show more code that shows how you're initializing it.

Answer (score 3):

**Android**

If you want to remove an AnchorNode from a scene then parent.removeChild(child) or node.setParent(null) is the recommended wayin Android ARCore.

To get ARCore to stop tracking an Anchor, you can use yourAnchor.detach().

More details here - Android ARCore

- https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Anchor.html#detach()

**Unity**

The Trackable class in unity has a method to create Anchors but not to destroy them. However, the approach that seems to be used is to destroy the Unity GameObject that represent the Anchor.

See an example from the Unity ARCore SDK here: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/9448df3e371e7e04a3e99ed6745890021d8f3e32/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/ObjectManipulation/Scripts/Manipulators/TranslationManipulator.cs

An extract of the relevant code:

```js
            GameObject oldAnchor = transform.parent.gameObject;

            Pose desiredPose = m_LastHit.Pose;

            Vector3 desiredLocalPosition = transform.parent.InverseTransformPoint(desiredPose.position);

            if (desiredLocalPosition.magnitude > MaxTranslationDistance)
            {
                desiredLocalPosition = desiredLocalPosition.normalized * MaxTranslationDistance;
            }

            desiredPose.position = transform.parent.TransformPoint(desiredLocalPosition);

            Anchor newAnchor = m_LastHit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(desiredPose);
            transform.parent = newAnchor.transform;

            Destroy(oldAnchor);
```